# Session resets when checking IsNewSession() after creating a new session

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

- IIS7.5
- Windows Server 2008
- Asp.net4.0

but it works fine in
IIS5.1

```
fileContent = @"<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td></td></tr></table>";


       // byte[] content = fileContent.ToByteArray();

        HttpContext currentRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

        //fileContent = currentRequest.Server.HtmlEncode(fileContent);  

        currentRequest.Response.Clear();
        currentRequest.Response.ClearContent();
        currentRequest.Response.ClearHeaders();
        //currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        currentRequest.Response.Buffer = true;


        //fileName = currentRequest.Server.UrlEncode( fileName); 



        if (toDownload)
        {
            currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
        }
        else
        {
            currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
        }
        currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileContent.Length.ToString());
        //currentRequest.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(StreamFileType.MSOffice2003ExcelDocument);
        currentRequest.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        currentRequest.Response.Write(fileContent);
        currentRequest.Response.Flush();
        currentRequest.Response.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

---

As soon as file opens in new page, new SessioniD is created.

if I Check the session it resets

```
if (this.Session.IsNewSession)
```

Comment: Do you really need to be clearing all the headers? If that is run after the session management code, it is possible it is clearing out the session cookie. Try removing the call to `currentRequest.Response.ClearHeaders();`